# Jquery functions (file loading) in order

Tags: jquery, load

I'm using the code below to load files in order and on page load. But I getting the

> $ is not a function

error for the last file "scripts.js". In other words, jquery and bootstrap files always load correctly, but the last file (my custom scripts) shows the error and nothing custom made works. What am I doing worng? Thanks for any help :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chamajquery() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    chamabootstrap();
}
function chamabootstrap() {
    var element2 = document.createElement("script");
    element2.src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element2);
    chamascriptsmanuais();
}
function chamascriptsmanuais() {
    var element3 = document.createElement("script");
    element3.src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/scripts.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element3);
}
window.addEventListener("load", chamajquery);
```

Comment: It's too early to use the prior script immediately after you append it. It still needs to load which is asynchronous.  Use a load event on the script element

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Btw why are you need to _append_ your scripts by using **both** Javascript and PHP? That seems a bit "overengineered" to me.

Comment: PHP to get the child theme's URL (Wordpress). And JS for the rest. I don't think is the best solution, but it works and increases page speed insights points (my client's main goal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would expect the scripts to be appended to head and not body
2. Your issue could be a timing issue
3. Why use this convoluted way? If you want to make the page load faster, just add all 3 scripts just before the `</body>` tag

---

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Alternative using onload (can be changed to addEventListener)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chamajquery() {
    const element1 = document.createElement("script");
    element1.onload=chamabootstrap;
    element1.src1 = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(element1);
}
function chamabootstrap() {
    const element2 = document.createElement("script");
    element2.onload=chamascriptsmanuais;
    element2.src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(element2);
}
function chamascriptsmanuais() {
    const element3 = document.createElement("script");
    element3.src = "<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/assets/js/scripts.js";
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(element3);
}
window.addEventListener("load", chamajquery);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm using those functions to load the scripts because of google page speed insights and their onload/defer directives. I need to get the highest score possible for my client. If i do what you recomend, the score will decrease around 10 points :/